# Rmd: access `yaml_metadata_block`

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

In `R Markdown`, How to exactly access metadata from non-header [`yaml_metadata_block`](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#yaml-metadata-block)?

My attempt doesn't quite work:

```
---
title: "My YAML block test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    md_extensions: +yaml_metadata_block
---

next we want to define some data on-the-fly using YAML:

---
myparam: somestring
---

And try using it in the document:

This is first attempt -  myparam is: $myparam$
This is second attempt - myparam is: `r print(myparam)`
```

Comment: Not sure, but [this](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1950#issuecomment-74613325) might help.

Comment: thanks, haven't yet figured out how to make `knitr` call `pandoc` with multiple input files as command line arguments, i.e. `pandoc main.md additional.yaml --to latex --from markdown`